# Adonis js How to reorder of creation of tables schema for migration to mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js, adonis.js

Problem is at the time of migration my child tables created at first and it could not find parents table and not able to assign the foreign key of parent table primary key and i get the error as below.

> here warehouses is children and the companies is parent
>
> at Runner.
>   (/Volumes/DATA/paras/adonis-js/smart-helmet-backend/smarthelmet/node_modules/knex/lib/runner.js:213:19)
>   code: 'ER_FK_CANNOT_OPEN_PARENT',   errno: 1824,   sqlMessage: 'Failed
>   to open the referenced table \'companies\'',   sqlState: 'HY000',
>   index: 0,   sql:    'alter table `warehouses` add constraint
>   `warehouses_company_id_foreign` foreign key (`company_id`) references
>   `companies` (`id`)' }

Answer (score 4):

you can change the migration file name.

- migration file name is unique this create file name using date so you can copy your child file numeric name and then replace parent file name numeric data and decrease number by one of your parent file
- if child filename **1503250034280_token.js** and prent file name **1565022160220_email_schema.js** like this then change parent name 
  like this `1503250034279_email_schema.js` then you run migration it's work

Comment: looking for more standard way.

Comment: or first, create parent migration then create child migration

Comment: Naming is standard way in knex to decide in which order migration files are run. Otherwise you need to write both migrations in single file to assure that operations are done in correct order.